# xml parsing using minidom and python

Tags: python, minidom

I have an xml like below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Samplexml>"
<CustomProperty>
   <Name>Test1</Name>
   <Value>TestValue1</Value>
</CustomProperty>
</Samplexml>`
```

I am trying to get the values Test1 and TestValue1. I am trying multiple ways but not able to get the values. How to get the values by not using something like "getElementsbyTagName"Name"/"Value"" as Child nodes names keep on changing.

Comment: You dont want to use getElementsbyTagName ? Is there a reason for that

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that you will not be using Name and Value to find its text because it will be changing. So you can use something like below which should help you solve your issue.Also I assume that your tag named  will be same

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
    for child in tree.find('CustomProperty'):
        print(child.text)
```

For this example code you will get your output like below:

```
    Test1
    TestValue1
```

Your xml file seems to have an extra character at the ending, please change that as well like the below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Samplexml>
    <CustomProperty>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Value>TestValue1</Value>
    </CustomProperty>
    </Samplexml>
```

Comment: Thanks Chetan, Is there a way to read each childNode at a time. I want to assign each value to a variable.

Comment: For your other question, you can create a empty list and then you can append the values to that list which comes out of for loop